# "Symbol not found" error, (possibly) due to recent upgrade to R2017b?

Tags: macos, matlab

I'm getting an error when I try to use imerode() from the command line, e.g.

```
test=magic([100 100])>200;
imclose(test,strel('disk',10,0));
```

I get this error:

> Error using images.internal.morphmex Invalid MEX-file
>   '/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/toolbox/images/images/+images/+internal/morphmex.mexmaci64':
>   dlopen(/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/toolbox/images/images/+images/+internal/morphmex.mexmaci64,
>   6): Symbol not found: _OSAtomicDecrement32Barrier   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/bin/maci64/./libcudart.8.0.dylib
>   Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib  in
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/bin/maci64/./libcudart.8.0.dylib.
>
> Error in images.internal.morphop (line 103)
>           B = images.internal.morphmex(mex_method, B, nhood, height, unpacked_M);
>
> Error in imdilate (line 135) B =
>   images.internal.morphop(A,se,'dilate',mfilename,varargin{:});
>
> Error in imclose (line 82)
>       outputImage = imerode(imdilate(inputImage,se,packopt,M),se,packopt,M);

I'm on OS X 10.9.5, with MATLAB R2017b.
I've checked that morphmex.mexmaci64 is there in the given path (above).
Not sure where /./ refers to, but libcudart.8.0.dylib is in maci64 folder.
Not sure where /usr/lib/... is.

EDIT

I have uninstalled R2017b and installed R2017a (why not, just in case...) and when trying to run the same code, I now get this error (which seems worse...)

> ---
>
> ### Segmentation violation detected at Mon Nov 13 13:44:29 2017
>
> Configuration:   Crash Decoding      : Disabled - No sandbox or build
>   area path   Crash Mode          : continue (default)   Current
>   Graphics Driver: Unknown hardware    Current Visual      : Quartz
>   Default Encoding    : ISO-8859-1   Deployed            : false   Host
>   Name           : eduroam-206-52.nomadic.bris.ac.uk   MATLAB
>   Architecture : maci64   MATLAB Entitlement ID: 1803495   MATLAB Root
>   : /Applications/MATLAB_R2017a.app   MATLAB Version      : 9.2.0.556344
>   (R2017a)   OpenGL              : hardware   Operating System    :
>   Darwin 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Mon Jan 11 18:17:34 PST
>   2016; root:xnu-2422.115.15~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64   Processor ID
>   : x86 Family 6 Model 69 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel   Virtual Machine
>   : Java 1.7.0_75-b13 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
>   Server VM mixed mode   Window System       : Quartz
>
> Fault Count: 2
>
> Abnormal termination: Trace trap

Can upload error file for rest of message (too long to paste here).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like a bug or installation error

Comment: So I have just reinstalled... and I think things have gotten worse... Please see edited post for details.

Comment: Redowload th ebinaries, and ultimatelly, ask Mathworks

Comment: OK sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out R2017a, b not compatible with OS Mavericks.
Rolled back to R2016a.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an installation problem or maybe it is due to the update.

Try to run the following commands in your console:

```
restoredefaultpath();
rehash toolboxcache;
```

If everything works without errors, then run:

```
savepath();
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply. I had already tried that (from some other forum, maybe Mathworks), but it didn't help. Currently reinstalling...